# Modern approach to notify Silverlight clients about data changes

Tags: .net, silverlight, notifications, client-server, crud

I am just about to implement some kind of Silverlight "notification" code so Silverlight  clients can get message about database CRUD passed on server-side.

I am wondering about the modern approaches to realize that task.

The old one I found here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx

Not sure if it is still  a good idea... Any clue?